# ASSERT failure in QList<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:/Qt/Qt5.12.11/5.12.11/mingw73_32/include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 548

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I am getting the following error and I don't understand where is my error. I think the error is here commandColumn[index.row()], but not sure about it. Could you help me with this and explain what I'm doing wrong.

**mytablemodel.h**

```
#ifndef MYTABLEMODEL_H
#define MYTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QStringList>

class MyTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTableModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    // QAbstractItemModel interface
public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

private:
    QStringList headerLabels;
    QVector<QString> commandColumn;
    QVector<float> valueColumn;
};

#endif // MYTABLEMODEL_H
```

**mytablemodel.cpp**

```
#include "mytablemodel.h"

MyTableModel::MyTableModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
    headerLabels << "Comamnd" << "Value";

    commandColumn << "txt" << "tx" << "txt";
    valueColumn << 7.5f << 10000 << 1;
}

int MyTableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return commandColumn.size();
}

int MyTableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return valueColumn.size();
}

QVariant MyTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid()) {
        return QVariant();
    }

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        if (index.column() == 0) {
            return commandColumn[index.row()];
        } else if (index.column() == 1) {
            return valueColumn[index.row()];
        }
    }

    return QVariant();
}

QVariant MyTableModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole && orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        return headerLabels[section];
    }

    return QVariant();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mytablemodel.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyTableModel *model = new MyTableModel(this);
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

There is only one tableview in mainwindow.ui

I am getting the following error:*ASSERT failure in QList::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:/Qt/Qt5.12.11/5.12.11/mingw73_32/include/QtCore/qlist.h, line 548*

Comment: Why you think commandColumn (QVector<QString>) causes problem in QList? QStringList inherits QList (headerLabels). Better use debugger, do not think.

Comment: What's in `mainwindow.h` and `ui_mainwindow.h`? I doubt we can reproduce the error without those.

Comment: Surely `columnCount` should just return 2?

Comment: @Botje Yes, that was the mistake. Why should it just return 2?

Comment: ... because you have a commandColumn and a valueColumn and code that only ever pulls from one of those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` method only handles the cases where column index is 0 or 1, so your `columnCount` method should return 2 instead of the number of rows again.